# How to specify 50 vec3 for each vertex in vertex shader?

Tags: attributes, shader, vertex

I have to design a GLSL code the handle some unusual calculations. The scene contains 2048 vertex and the position is predefined. While there are 50 vec3 for each vertex as attribute and will be used in the vertex shader. Since the max attribute location for each vertex is typically limited to be 16, so how can I specify such amount of data for vertex?

Maybe texture lookup in vertex shader is one way to solve this problem, but I am not sure whether it is the optimal way.

Comment: Lookup is the only way in you case, though it will be tricky if you want, for example, to pack arbitrary floating-point values with 32-bit precision.

Comment: I am not sure there would be any interpolations or not when I do the texture lookup in vertex shader? For example, I design a texture in 2048X50 RGB half float format, and then I am looking 133th vertex's value, which should be located at (1/50, 1/2048*133), (2/50, 1/2048*133), (3/50, 1/2048*133),  ... , (1, 1/2048*133) , I can get the specific value or the some interpolated value?

Comment: You can get specific pixel value using point texture filtering. And you must remember about precision/ Half-float is limited 6.55 × 10^4 at max and 6.10 × 10^-5 at min.